# Recording from multiple channels through sox

Tags: node.js, macos, wav, microphone, sox

I am trying to record 2 different microphones through Sox for one of my application. I am currently just testing on Mac terminal for the audio recording. However, I am only able to get audio through one microphone.

The sox command I am using is:

`sox -b 32 -e unsigned-integer -r 96k -c 2 -d --clobber --buffer $((96000*2*10)) /tmp/soxrecording.wav trim 0 10`

Which give me a good .wav file.

I have two different usb microphones which show up as 2 channel I/p each in Sound/System Preferences. I tried to do `-c 4` with the sox command to record from both microphones.

`sox -b 32 -e unsigned-integer -r 96k -c 4 -d --clobber --buffer $((96000*2*10)) /tmp/soxrecording.wav trim 0 10`

However, I get a warning saying; 
`sox WARN formats: can't set 4 channels; using 2`

And I can just get audio in from only one usb microphone. I have been trying to fiddle and understand what’s wrong but any hints would be really helpful.

Comment: I think just because you have two devices doesn't mean you have double the channels. You need to specify the two input files using the `hw:1,0,0` format. So basically you have two input files. See this thread for more details http://sox.10957.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-inputs-with-SOX-td5061.html. AUDIODEV is the environment variable to control the device. But I am not sure if you can have two device specified in that. But specifying them as multiple files in input should work. The format of the command is `sox <fileoptions> file <fileoptions> file <outputoptions> outputfile`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am not sure what this means. I don't have input files. I have input devices. So running `AUDIODEV=hw:1,0,0 sox -b 32 -e unsigned-integer -r 44100 -c 2 ~/Desktop/tempRecord1.wav ~/Desktop/tempRecording2.wav` gives me `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `/Users/blah/Desktop/tempRecord1.wav': No such file or directory`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Also, not sure how to get those `hw` device numbers on Mac. I can't run `aplay -l` or `aplay -L`

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Also, just using `sox -r 44100 hw:1,0 -t .ogg ch1_.ogg silence 1 0.1 5% 1 1.0 5% : newfile : restart` for one default microphone on Mac gives me `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `hw:1,0': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you are using `ALSA`, then run two different SOX command and have to specify the hardware you use for each one.

Please refer to [soc, play, rec man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rec), basically you may use the `-d, --default-device` parameter when starting your command to specify which device you want to use.

Something like (simplified):

```
sox -r 44100 -c 2 -e s -t alsa hw:4,0 -d 
sox -r 44100 -c 2 -e s -t alsa hw:3,0 -d
```

This [page](http://sox.10957.n7.nabble.com/Changing-the-audio-input-card-td1645.html) and this [page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13088) may also help you.

Comment: I am on Mac OS and running your commands gives me `sox FAIL formats: no handler for given file type `alsa`